# zod validation hindering form submission

Tags: crud, react-hook-form, zod

I am working on an IdeaCard project typical ClearScore take-home assessment with basic CRUD functionality. I am using react form hook and want to introduce zod for validation. However when i add zod resolver into the form the handle(onSubmit) function does not fire. When i remove it, the event fires and data is stored in localStorage.

Here is my code below for both the card creation and the logic for handling CRUD functions in my page.tsx:

```
'use client';

import * as z from "zod";
import { Idea } from '@/lib/types';
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';



const EditIdeaSchema = z.object({
  uuid: z.string(),
  title: z.string().min(5, {
    message: "⚠ Title must be at least 5 characters.",
  })
    .max(16, {
      message: "⚠ Title must not be longer than 16 characters.",
    }),
  description: z.string().optional(),   
  content: z.string().max(140 , "Must be less than").optional(),  
  createdTime: z.date(),
  updatedTime: z.date()
});

type EditIdeaSchemaType = z.infer<typeof EditIdeaSchema>;


interface IdeaCardProps {
  idea: Idea;
  onDelete: () => void;
  onSave: (updatedIdea: Idea) => void;

}

const IdeaCard: React.FC<IdeaCardProps> = ({ idea, onDelete, onSave }) => {
  const [charCount, setCharCount] = useState(0);
  const isSavedRef = useRef(false);
  
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue, 
    formState: { errors },
    reset,
  } = useForm<EditIdeaSchemaType>({resolver: 
    zodResolver(EditIdeaSchema)});

  useEffect(() => {
    reset({
      title: idea.title || '',
      description: idea.description || '',
      content: idea.content || '',
    });
  }, [idea, reset]);

 const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Idea> = async (data) => {
    console.log('onSubmit function is triggered');
    console.log('submit executed');
    console.log('Form Data:', data);
    try {
      const updatedIdea: Idea = EditIdeaSchema.parse({
        ...idea,
        title: data.title,
        description: data.description,
        content: data.content,
        updatedTime: new Date(),
      });

      onSave(updatedIdea);
      isSavedRef.current = true;

      const updatedIdeas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ideas") || "[]").map(
        (storedIdea: Idea) =>
          storedIdea.uuid === updatedIdea.uuid ? updatedIdea : storedIdea
      );
      localStorage.setItem("ideas", JSON.stringify(updatedIdeas));

      // toast notif
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof z.ZodError) {
        console.error('Validation error:', error.errors);
        // toast notif
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error:', error);
        // toast notif
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    className={` form relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg p-4 mb-4 lg:w-1/4 
      ${isSavedRef.current ? 'bg-green-100' : ''}`} >
       <div className="flex justify-between items-center mt-0 mb-2">
          <p className="text-gray-500 text-sm">
            Created: {idea.createdTime ? new Date(idea.createdTime).toLocaleString() : 'N/A'}
          </p>
          </div>
      <div>
        <input
          {...register('title')}
          type="text"
          className="font-bold text-lg mb-2 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline border-b-2 border-blue-500 w-full"
          placeholder="Enter title..."
          autoFocus
        />
        {errors.title && <span className="text-red-500">{errors.title.message}</span>}

        <textarea
          {...register('description')}
          className="resize-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full"
          placeholder="Idea description..."
        />
        {errors.description && <span className="text-red-500">{errors.description.message}</span>}

        <textarea
          {...register('content')}
          className="resize-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline w-full"
          placeholder="Enter your ideas here..."
          onChange={(e) => {
            const newContent = e.target.value;
            setCharCount(newContent.length);
          }}
        />
        {errors.content && <span className="text-red-500">{errors.content.message}</span>}

        <p className="text-gray-500 text-sm ml-10 mt-2">
            Character Count: {charCount}/150
          </p>
        </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={onDelete}
                className=" absolute bottom-0 left-0 p-2 cursor-pointer text-red-500 mr-2 text-4xl"
              >
                <MdDeleteForever />
              </button> 
              <div>
              <button 
                type="submit"
                className={`absolute bottom-0 right-0 mr-4 p-2 ${
                  isSavedRef.current ? 'bg-green-500' : 'bg-blue-500'
                } text-white px-3 py-1 mb-2 rounded hover:${
                  isSavedRef.current ? 'bg-green-600' : 'bg-blue-600'
                } focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline`}
              >
                {isSavedRef.current ? 'Saved' : 'Save'}
              </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>    
    </>
  );
};

export default IdeaCard;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
'use client';

import { Idea } from '@/lib/types';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { sampleIdeas } from '@/lib/constants';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import IdeaCard from '@/components/IdeaCard';
import Navigation from '@/components/Navbar';

export default function Home() {
  const [ideas, setIdeas] = useState<Idea[]>([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedIdeas = localStorage.getItem('ideas');
    if (savedIdeas) {
      setIdeas(JSON.parse(savedIdeas))
      console.log('fetching data from localStorage', JSON.parse(savedIdeas))
    }else {
      setIdeas(sampleIdeas);
      localStorage.setItem('ideas', JSON.stringify(sampleIdeas));
      console.log('Setting sample ideas in local storage');
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ideas.length > 0) {
      localStorage.setItem('ideas', JSON.stringify(ideas));
      console.log("setting local storage," , JSON.stringify(ideas))
    }
  }, [ideas]);

  const handleAddNewCard = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();

    const newCard : Idea = {
    uuid: uuidv4(),
    title: '',
    description: '',
    createdTime: currentDate,
    updatedTime: currentDate,
    content: ''
  };

   setIdeas([...ideas, newCard]);
};

const handleSave = (updatedIdea: Idea, index: number) => {
  const newIdeas = [...ideas];
  newIdeas[index] = updatedIdea;
  setIdeas(newIdeas);
  localStorage.setItem('ideas', JSON.stringify(newIdeas));
  toast.success(' Save Successful', {
    position: "bottom-center"
  })
};

const handleDelete = (index: number) => {
  const newIdeas = [...ideas];
  newIdeas.splice(index, 1);
  setIdeas(newIdeas);
  localStorage.removeItem('ideas');
  toast.success('️ Delete Successful', {
    position: "bottom-center"
  })
};

const handleSortByCreatedTime = () => {
  const sortedIdeas = [...ideas].sort(
    (a, b) => new Date(a.createdTime).getTime() - new Date(b.createdTime).getTime()
  );
  setIdeas(sortedIdeas);
  toast.success(' Sort Successful', {
    position: "bottom-center"
  })
};

 const handleSortByTitle = () => {
  const sortedIdeas = [...ideas].sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
  setIdeas(sortedIdeas);
  toast.success(' Sort Successful', {
    position: "bottom-center"
  })
};

 const handleSortByTitleReverse = () => {
  const sortedIdeas = [...ideas].sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
  setIdeas(sortedIdeas);
  toast.success(' Sort Successful', {
    position: "bottom-center"
  })
};

const handleClearIdeas = () => {
  setIdeas([]);
  localStorage.removeItem('ideas');
  toast.success('  Clear Successful', {
    position: "bottom-center"
  })
};


const handleSampleIdeas = () => {
    setIdeas(sampleIdeas);
    localStorage.setItem('ideas', JSON.stringify(sampleIdeas));
    toast.success(' Sample Ideas Added', {
      position: 'bottom-center',
    });
}

  return (
    <>
      <Navigation onAddNewCard={handleAddNewCard} />
      <header className="flex flex-col items-center">
        <div className="flex">
        <button onClick={handleSampleIdeas} 
          className="bg-purple-500 text-white p-2 mb-2 rounded text-sm mt-4 font-bold
         hover:bg-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline justify-center">
          Sample Ideas
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleSortByCreatedTime} 
          className="bg-orange-500 text-white p-2 mb-2 rounded text-sm mt-4 ml-3 font-bold
         hover:bg-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline justify-center">
          Sort By Date
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleSortByTitle} 
          className="bg-green-500 text-white p-2 mb-2 rounded text-sm mt-4 ml-3 font-bold
         hover:bg-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline justify-center">
          Sort A-Z
        </button>
          <button onClick={handleSortByTitleReverse} 
          className="bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 mb-2 rounded text-sm mt-4  ml-3 font-bold
         hover:bg-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline justify-center">
           Sort Z-A
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={handleClearIdeas}
          className="bg-red-500 text-white p-2 mb-2 rounded text-sm mt-4 ml-3 font-bold
           hover:bg-gray-600 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline justify-center"
        >
          Delete All
        </button>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main className="flex flex-wrap justify-around">
        {ideas.map((idea: Idea, index: number) => (
          <IdeaCard key={idea.uuid} idea={idea} onDelete={() => handleDelete(index)} 
          onSave={(updatedIdea: Idea) => handleSave(updatedIdea, index)} 
          />
        ))}
      </main>
      <input type="text" style={{ opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', zIndex: -1 }} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I have added console logs to establish where the logic breaks.
And i have also removed components and added them one at a time to determine the source of errors.